# How to organize "tabs" below the navigationBar? Best practices?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm quite new to objective-c so i'm thinking a lot about best practices. My current problem is that I'm asking myself how to build my own kind of TabBar below the `navigationBar`. I created two `UIButton`s which should switch the subviews below the buttons.

Just to illustrate my architecture — it should look more or less like the header in the Gowalla app:
http://cl.ly/7pQv

Of course I could just create two subviews and use `removeFromSuperview` and `addSubview`.

But isn't there a better way to organize them? Maybe by using a `UIViewController`? But that would be some kind of nesting which Apple doesn't recommend, isn't it? Because I don't want to change the whole view of the active `navigationController`-view. My `UIButton`s should stay in place, just want to switch content below …

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. One is to stack views on top of each other and set the alpha to 0.0 for the views you want to hide. The buttons then are simple UIButtons (as you indicated). You can do most of the work in Interface Builder (although it gets kinda messy).

Advantages: quick and dirty, no need to add/remove. Disadvantages: all the code for the "different views" is in one class which can make things messy.

There are other ways, but frankly, the amount of code in my opinion (as well as the support and the fact Apple might ding you) don't really make them worth it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I hoped there would be a memory friendlier practice, but ok — I will solve it kinda like you said.

Comment: How is "Quick and dirty" an advantage?

Comment: Advantage: Easy to maintain, easy to understand, easy to build, easy to test.